# Prevent event bubbling in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been asked to implement a card design with a toggle on top. The card is supposed to be clickable, but touches should not bubble up from the toggle.

What is the best way to prevent interactions with the Toggle from effecting the Button with this layout?

```swift
Button(action: action) {
    HStack {
        Text("Button text")
        Toggle("Toggle text", isOn: $isOn)
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Toggle` is a specialized `Button`. It should not be in the label of another button.

Comment: The best way is not put one control into another. Btw, just curious, why would you need that? Why not, schematically, `HStack[Button, Toggle]`?

Comment: This was a request from designers. I did voice my concern about nesting controls.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments, you should avoid having a `Toggle` inside a Button.

But if you want to prevent your button from "bubbling", just use the `.onTapGesture()` modifier instead.

Here's the code:

```
            HStack {
                Text("Button text")
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor) // This is only if you want to have the text blue
                Toggle("Toggle text", isOn: $isOn)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor) // This is only if you want to have the text blue
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                action()
            }
```

Comment: I found https://mobilea11y.com/guides/swiftui/swiftui-semantic-views/ which discusses solutions for accessibility when using `onTapGesture`.Still not sure about this answer though, because presumably the event would still bubble up and affect anything higher up the chain.

Comment: onTapGesture seems to bubble as well.